# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<>' to ''

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[NonAction]
protected void PrepareNewsCommentModel(NewsCommentModel model, NewsComment newsComment)
{
  if (newsComment == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("newsComment");
  if (model       == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("model");

  model.Id = newsComment.Id;
  model.CommentTitle = newsComment.CommentTitle;
  model.CustomerName = newsComment.CustomerName;
  model.CommentText = newsComment.CommentText;

}

public ActionResult Comments(int number)
{
  if (!_newsSettings.Enabled)
    return RedirectToRoute("HomePage");

  var newsComment = _newsService.GetNewsComment(number);
  var model = new NewsCommentModel();
  PrepareNewsCommentModel(model,newsComment);

  return View(model);
}
```

This is my error:

```
Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from
'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Yapi.Core.Domain.News.NewsComment>' to
'Yapi.Core.Domain.News.NewsComment'
D:\YAPI\Projects\ASCS-Portal\Yapi.Web\Controllers\NewsController.cs 420
40
Yapi.Web
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Do you have question or a problem statment?

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you the issue. `newsComment` is an `IList<NewsComment>` but your `PrepareNewsCommentModel` method expects a `NewsComment` instead.

Try using Linq's [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) extension method:

```
var newsComment = _newsService.GetNewsComment(number).First();
```

Or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) if your `GetNewsComment` method can possibly return an empty list:

```
var newsComment = _newsService.GetNewsComment(number).FirstOrDefault();
```